# ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,256,1024,1021]

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I got tensorflow code from my colleague and trying to run it on DGX-1. However, code throws exception:

```
ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,256,1024,1021] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
[[{{node Optimizer/gradients/Decoder/Decoder/LeakyRelu_9_grad/Select_1}} = Select[T=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](Optimizer/gradients/Decoder/Decoder/LeakyRelu_9_grad/GreaterEqual, Optimizer/gradients/Decoder/Decoder/LeakyRelu_9_grad/zeros, Optimizer/gradients/Decoder/Decoder/conv2d_5/Conv2D_grad/Conv2DBackpropInput)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

Following things to be noted:

```
Batch is already set to 1.
Every time, exception is raised on different epoch number.
I have tried following settings (not working):
config.gpu_options.allocator_type ='BFC'
config.gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction = 0.90
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I tried different image sizes (some of the sizes were either causing code exceptions or still having memory issue), luckily, one of the sizes fixed issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer is running out of memory. There are a few things you can do:

- Decrease the number of neurons in your `Dense`, `Conv2D` layers
- Use smaller `float` data types for your input, namely `np.float16` rather than `np.float64`
- Use a smaller `batch_size` (or increase `steps_per_epoch`)
- Use grayscale images (so 1 channel instead of three)
- Reduce the number of layers
- Use more `MaxPooling2D` layers, and increase their pool size
- Use larger `strides` in your `Conv2D` layers
- Reduce the size your images (you can use `PIL` for that)
- Apply dropout